# Tension in a massless string around a pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

A pulley having some mass has a massless string around it, with two unequal masses at the end of the string. Sufficient friction is present between pulley and the string such that the string does not slip on the pulley .

The tensions in the massless string on the two sides of pulley will be same or different?

According to me the tensions on the two sides should be different so as to provide a net torque to the pulley .But what I have learned till now is that the tension in a massless string is same throughout.

Let the tensions on the two sides of the string be $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Writing equation for rotational motion of pulley we have (T1-T2)R = Ia

Since the pulley has non zero moment of inertia and angular acceleration ,T1 WILL NOT BE EQUAL TO T2.

I am having difficulty in understanding that how can a massless string have different tensions.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, to simplify things, the pulleys are assumed to be massless/frictionless.

In this case, if the tensions were *different*. we would have a net torque. However, I=0 so this is impossible without a persistent infinite angular acceleration (which is also not possible). So we take the tensions to be the same.

Similarly, in the frictionless case, there is no way for the string to transmit torque, and different tensions must result in a nonzero torque, so the tensions can't be different.

You are correct in saying that a pulley with mass will make the string have different tensions. In this case, we can use the net force on the pulley and its angular acceleration (which can be calculated from constraints) to form another equation to account for the extra variable introduced.

Comment: Okay...So this means the massless string will have different tensions on the two sides.But this is what I am unable to comprehend that how can a massless string have different tensions across its length.Please address this issue .I understand what happens in case the pulley is massless,but in this case the pulley has mass.

Comment: @Vibhor: Why do you think that a massless string cannot have different tensions? There's no reason for it -- when the string is obstruction-free this happens because otherwise parts of the string would fly off to infinity. But in the case of a pulley, the pulley is there to equalize the imbalance.

Comment: Thanks.This is exactly what i want to understand .Could you elaborate " when the string is obstruction-free this happens because otherwise parts of the string would fly off to infinity " .

Comment: @Vibhor: If the tension was uneven, parts of the string would have a net force. It's massless, so the net force gives infinite acceleration.

Comment: Nice explaination !! Now how is this different when massless string passes over a pulley having sufficient friction ?

Comment: @Vibhor: Well, the pulley needs mass too. When the pulley has mass and friction, the force imbalance results in a net torque on the pulley (it cannot do so if the pulley is massless or frictionless), and is taken care of.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding .But I didnt quite understand what you meant .

Comment: @Vibhor: Draw free body diagrams for the pulley and strings. Note that there is a possible situation when the strings have 0 net force only when the pulley has mass and friction.

Comment: By drawing FBD of complete string as a whole(i.e leftpart,middle curved part over pulley and right part),I find there are two forces acting on the string .First one is Normal force from the pulley .The net resultant normal will be upwards.Second friction from pulley .How should I analyse this ?

Comment: @Vibhor: Consider the two parts of the string, first.

Comment: Okay...Let the right mass be heavier .In that case left part of string moves up and right part of string moves down.   Forces on left part -Normal(leftwards) and friction (downwards) ; Forces on right part -Normal(rightwards) and friction(upwards) .

Comment: Please reply to the above post .

Comment: @Vibhor: What do I reply to? You haven't asked anything.

Comment: Sorry for that...Thanks for replying...Is my assessment correct regarding forces on the two parts (i.e left and right) ?I am not clear how do the forces on the string add up to be zero .

Comment: @Vibhor: Go deeper. Include the pulley as well, analyse the situation when the pulley is and isn't massless and try to make the tensions inequal in both.  It won't work for a massless pulley. (And I'm not going to check your work for you :/)

Comment: If you are in no mood to help,then why reply in the first place .You could have allowed somebody else to respond . You were pretty fast when it came to dismissing the question as homework help. Just remember your days of engineering prep when you would have loved to clear your concepts. Its a real shame to get such a response from the moderator . Anyways ...Thanks for sparing your precious time and energy .

Comment: @Vibhor: I _do_ want to help. However, I'm not going to do your work for you.  

And as a moderator I am supposed to enforce the rules, which I did pretty quickly.

Comment: @ Manishearth :When did i asked you to work for me ?I am working on the lines you are guiding me .Didnt I ? I am just requesting you to check my work, so that i can proceed further.Is that asking too much ? Please put yourself in my shoes and see.

Comment: @Vibhor: Go up three comments. I checked your work, and told you what to do next. Thing is, if I keep doing that, you'll never understand the concept here, not properly. Basically I was asking you to experiment with the system. It's not entirely a "fixed path" where I can check which track you're on. You will understand the concept automatically if you do this for a while.

(Also, I remember being in your shoes a few years ago; and experimenting with the system is where I got my conceptual understanding from)

Comment: There's a big difference between helping and spoonfeeding. I didn't want to do the latter; as in the long run it doesn't help.

Comment: Please for heavens sake dont say you were spoonfeeding me .Anyways...i can sense your mood .Thanks for bearing with me .Good Luck.

Comment: @Vibhor: I wasn't, but I didn't want to either.

Comment: You werent helping me either,after a certain point.Forget about the long run,its not helping me in the present.Please accept this ;the question I have put on the forum is a real good one .Please dont put your inability to explain the matter on something else.Good old saying of not spoonfeeding somebody when one is incapable of explaining .You may find it strange,but when I put the question,I wished it was you who should answer it .To my horror,you responded,and that too,in tagging it as homework .I think you are a good student,but it will take a while before you become a good mentor .

Comment: @Vibhor: "inability to explain the matter"? No, I could explain further. I just won't because (a) I don't have that much time, (b) I've already tried quite hard to explain it in the comments above and given IMO enough material to get through with it. I'm not here to mentor people. Giving a head start and clearing up concepts is OK, but micro-mentoring is not something I want to do here. Sorry if that doesn't help you.

Comment: Also, read the comment thread again. I told you to draw FBDs. You started and gave me an update, I again pointed you in the correct direction. You again gave a picture of where you were, I again pointed you in the right direction by telling you to go deeper, and specify how. I also mentioned that I wasn't going to check your work. Why? I didn't want you to comment on my answer with every step and ask for approval (I got the impression that this could happen from the previous comments, because the steps you had shown were very small ones). That's all.

Comment: After this, you stopped commenting about the problem and switched to talking about how I wasn't helping you. 0_O

Comment: Regarding the HW tag, it's a rule, and it depends on the type of the question (it even applies to some questions which aren't HW).

Comment: Aha…so somebody has a few words for me.Instead of making so many excuses how you tried to help me ,you could have explained the concepts involved in the above situation .Wait!!! Did I forget you are not here to micro-mentor.Of all the excuses you have made ,one thing that I could have readily accepted is that you didn’t have enough time.That’s a pretty valid reason.Afterall you have your own studies to take care .You trying hard to explain is not true.Yes ,you tried initially,but gave up very soon,for reasons better known to you.

Comment: ”I am not here to mentor people” –How can you say this ?First being a moderator and second ,you willingly responded to the question .This in itself puts you in the role of a mentor.I understand this is a free site and people willingly exchange ideas .But if you respond to somebody ,then you should take him right through the problem.If you cant then ask someone else to take over .It doesn’t mean you spoonfeed .There is a subtle difference in spoonfeeding and guiding somebody through exchange of ideas .Its here where experience comes into count.Rightly said “Experience is the mother of wisdom” .

Comment: I was merely looking for a little piece of knowledge ,which you were unwilling to share.
The thing which irked me was “(And I'm not going to check your work for you :/ ).That was very rude . You need to understand ,this site is not a forum.It is a question and answers site .” but micro-mentoring is not something I want to do here” Either you give a complete answer yourself ,or guide the person with a healthy conversation. You cannot shy away from your role.

Comment: You say I started  talking about how you weren't helping me ,I was merely responding to you.Do you like if you are conversing with somebody  and he turns his back on you. If you read back ,you will notice I wanted to end this fruitless conversation.I am not here to demean anybody or involve in any baseless argument.I am here to learn the science .

Comment: Regarding tagging this question as homework is nonsense.This is a conceptual question ,not a plug and chug type .And I explained my line of thought briefly .Not that I didn’t put any effort.Its quite strange and funny that when I broke the initial concise explaination in few more lines ,it became acceptable to you .

Comment: @Vibhor: re: homework: It is _now_. It wasn't earlier.

Comment: @Vibhor: Again, _I did not give up on this_. I was completely willing to continue helping you. However, I did not want this to degrade into a conversation where you post a single step and I check it, and so on and so forth. That was the only reason I posted that comment.

Comment: @Vibhor: re: unwilling to share: No, I was willing to share, I wasn't willing to micro mentor. Regarding the role of a mentor: No, answering this doesn't put me into the role of the mentor. Nor does being a moderator. The _primary_ purpose of Physics.SE is not to help the OP (important, but not primary). It is to  create Q&As that will be useful to many others. This isn't a forum. And I don't think you can dictate my duties here.

Comment: Regarding the free exchange of ideas: Not exactly. In fact, long discussions like these are disallowed in the comments (they belong in [chat]). We are not here to guide people in long comment discussions. If clarification is required, we can provide it, but don't expect a single one-on-one mentoring here.

Comment: If you disagree with any of this, feel free to post on [meta]. I'm not going to continue discussing it here.